# Python Hive Metastore partition timeout

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, thrift, hive-metastore

We have ETL jobs in Python (Luigi). They all connect to Hive Metastore to get partitions info.

Code:

```
from hive_metastore import ThriftHiveMetastore
client = ThriftHiveMetastore.Client(protocol)
partitions = client.get_partition_names('sales', 'salesdetail', -1)
```

-1 is max_parts (max partitions returned)

It randomly times out like this:

```
  File "/opt/conda/envs/etl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/contrib/hive.py", line 210, in _existing_partitions
    partition_strings = client.get_partition_names(database, table, -1)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/etl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hive_metastore/ThriftHiveMetastore.py", line 1703, in get_partition_names
    return self.recv_get_partition_names()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/etl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hive_metastore/ThriftHiveMetastore.py", line 1716, in recv_get_partition_names
    (fname, mtype, rseqid) = self._iprot.readMessageBegin()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/etl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 126, in readMessageBegin
    sz = self.readI32()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/etl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 206, in readI32
    buff = self.trans.readAll(4)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/etl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 58, in readAll
    chunk = self.read(sz - have)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/etl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 159, in read
    self.__rbuf = StringIO(self.__trans.read(max(sz, self.__rbuf_size)))
  File "/opt/conda/envs/etl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 105, in read
    buff = self.handle.recv(sz)
timeout: timed out
```

This error happens occasionally.
There is 15 minute timeout on Hive Metastore.
When I investigate to run get_partition_names separately, it returns data within a few seconds.
Even when I set socket.timeout to 1 or 2 seconds, query completes.
There is no record of socket close connection message in Hive metastore logs `cat /var/log/hive/..log.out`

The tables it usually times out on have large number of partitions ~10K+. But as mentioned before, they only time out randomly. And they return partitions metadata quickly when that portion of code alone is tested.

Any ideas why it times out randomly, or how to catch these timeout errors in metastore logs, or how to fix them ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a thread overlap in LUIGI

We used a Singleton to implement a poor-man's connection pool. But Luigi's different worker threads stepped on each other, and caused strange behavior when one thread's get_partition_names conflict's with another's.

We fixed the issue by ensuring each thread's connection object gets its own 'key' in the connection pool (instead of all threads sharing the process id key)